# JS/JSp issue in IE 10 for scrollbar and sorting

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am facing issue in table where we are using scroll bar and sorting.

In compatible mode sorting option is coming where as not coming in non compatible mode

Please suggest changes in js or jsp

```
function makeScrollableTable(tbl, scrollFooter, height, hasSelectAllButton, hasAddButton, columnNo) {
    var c, pNode, hdr, ftr, wrapper, rect;
    //alert("Shree");
    if (typeof tbl == 'string') tbl = document.getElementById(tbl);
    pNode = tbl.parentNode;
    fixTableWidth(tbl);
    c = container.length;
    container[c] = document.createElement('<SPAN style="height: 100; overflow: auto;">');
    container[c].id = tbl.id + "Container";
    pNode.insertBefore(container[c], tbl);
    container[c].appendChild(tbl);
    container[c].style.width = tbl.clientWidth + 2 * tbl.clientLeft + scrollbarWidth();
    hdr = tbl.cloneNode(false);
    hdr.id += 'Header';
    hdr.appendChild(tbl.tHead.cloneNode(true));
    tbl.tHead.style.display = 'none';
    if (!scrollFooter || !tbl.tFoot) {
        ftr = document.createElement('<SPAN style="width:1;height:1;clip: rect(0 1 1 0);background-color:transparent;">');
        ftr.id = tbl.id + 'Footer';
        ftr.style.border = tbl.style.border;
        ftr.style.width = getActualWidth(tbl) + 2 * tbl.clientLeft;
        ftr.style.borderBottom = ftr.style.borderLeft = ftr.style.borderRight = 'none';
    } else {
        ftr = tbl.cloneNode(false);
        ftr.id += 'Footer';
        ftr.appendChild(tbl.tFoot.cloneNode(true));
        ftr.style.borderTop = 'none';
        tbl.tFoot.style.display = 'none';
    }
    wrapper = document.createElement('<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>');
    wrapper.id = tbl.id + 'Wrapper';
    pNode.insertBefore(wrapper, container[c]);
    wrapper.insertRow(0).insertCell(0).appendChild(hdr);
    wrapper.insertRow(1).insertCell(0).appendChild(container[c]);
    wrapper.insertRow(2).insertCell(0).appendChild(ftr);
    wrapper.align = tbl.align;
    tbl.align = hdr.align = ftr.align = 'left';
    hdr.style.borderBottom = 'none';
    tbl.style.borderTop = tbl.style.borderBottom = 'none';
    // adjust page size
    if (c == 0 && height == 'auto') {
        onResizeAdjustTable();
        onResizeHandler = window.onresize;
        window.onresize = onResizeAdjustTable;
    } else {
        container[c].style.height = height;
    }
    //added by Venkatesh Bhat e-mail:vb106@dcx
    //alert("");
    if (hasSelectAllButton) {
        //include select all button
        var selButton = document.createElement('<input id="_myButton11" type="button" value="Select All" onClick="selectAll();">');
        insertNode(selButton);
    }
    if (hasAddButton) {
        var btext = '<input id="_myButton12" type="button" value="Add" onClick="posCursor(\'' + tbl.id + '\',\'' + columnNo + '\');">';
        var addButton = document.createElement(btext);
        insertNode(addButton);
    }
}
//added by Venkatesh Bhat e-mail:vb106@dcx
function insertNode(toInsert) {
    var tbs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < tbs.length; i++) {
        if (tbs[i].type == "button") {
            var backButton = tbs[i];
            var text = backButton.value.toUpperCase();
            if (text == "BACK") {
                var pNode = backButton.parentNode;
                pNode.insertBefore(toInsert, backButton);
                var textNode = document.createTextNode("  ");
                pNode.insertBefore(textNode, backButton);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
//added by Venkatesh Bhat e-mail:vb106@dcx
function posCursor(tbl, columnNo) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tbl);
    var rows = table.rows;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        //cells = rows[i].cells;
        //if(columnNo > cells.length) continue;
        var cell = rows[i].cells[columnNo];
        if (getFocus(cell) == true) {
            selectCheckBox(rows[i].cells[0]);
            return;
        }
    }
}
//added by Venkatesh Bhat e-mail:vb106@dcx
function selectCheckBox(node) {
    var children = node.children;
    //check if this is a leaf node
    if (children.length == 0) {
        //if so then see if this is a checkbox input node
        if (node.tagName == "INPUT" && node.type == "checkbox") {
            node.checked = true;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        //this is a parent node
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            if (selectCheckBox(children[i]) == true) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
//added by Venkatesh Bhat e-mail:vb106@dcx
function getFocus(node) {
    var children = node.children;
    //check if this is a leaf node
    if (children.length == 0) {
        //if so then see if this is a text input node
        if (node.tagName == "INPUT" && node.type == "text" && node.value == "") {
            node.focus();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        //this is a parent node
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            if (getFocus(children[i]) == true) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
//added by Venkatesh Bhat e-mail:vb106@dcx
function selectAll() {
    //added by Venkatesh Bhat e-mail:vb106@dcx
    var button = document.getElementById('_myButton11');
    var butText = button.value;
    var tbs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    if (butText == 'Deselect All') {
        button.value = "Select All";
        for (var i = 0; i < tbs.length; i++) {
            if (tbs[i].type == "checkbox") {
                tbs[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        button.value = "Deselect All";
        for (var i = 0; i < tbs.length; i++) {
            if (tbs[i].type == "checkbox") {
                tbs[i].checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

function onResizeAdjustTable() {
    if (onResizeHandler) onResizeHandler();
    var rect = container[0].getClientRects()(0);
    var h = document.body.clientHeight - (rect.top + (document.body.scrollHeight - rect.bottom));
    container[0].style.height = (h > 0) ? h : 1;
}

function printPage() {
    var tbs = document.getElementsByTagName('TABLE');
    var e;
    for (var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) container[i].style.overflow = '';
    window.print();
    for (var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) container[i].style.overflow = 'auto';
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: sorting not working in non compatible mode but in compatible mode same code shows sorting option and works well

Comment: You are trying to reinvent the wheel. Why don't you consider about using jquery table plugins like [jQgrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) or [DataTable](http://datatables.net/)

Comment: Make sure, you are not getting any error in your log of browser debugging tool. If you are getting, please share for further understanding.

Comment: @Vinoth can u suggest the solution

Comment: @pRakash no logs in console

Comment: @ all need solution for this issue.

Comment: @All in IE 8/compatibility mode  table header shows sorting button but not visible in non compatibility mode